# Function to find the intersection between two large CSV files and add extra columns

Tags: python, list, csv, julia

I am trying to write a Python script to find the common rows between two large CSV files (file1 and file2) and write the common rows (file1 rows) into a separate file, with an additional column from file2.

Below is the code that I am currently using:

```
import csv
import io
import sys
import datetime

fd1 = io.open('compare_input2.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
fd2 = open('input.csv', 'r')

reader1 = csv.reader(fd1, delimiter=",")
reader2 = csv.reader(fd2, delimiter=",")

lst1 = tuple(reader1)
lst2 = tuple(reader2)
wfd = io.open('output.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
writer = csv.writer(wfd, delimiter=",", quotechar = '|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
matching = []
count = 0
match = 0
print(datetime.datetime.now())
for row1 in lst1:
    try:
        sys.stdout.write("{} rows compared, {} matches found\r".format(count,match))
        if row1 in lst2:
            matching.append(row1)
            match += 1
    except:
        print(len(matching))
        sys.exit(1)
count += 1
print(datetime.datetime.now())
#fd_out = io.open('matching.csv', 'w',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
#fd_out.write(str(matching))
#fd_out.close()
for row in matching:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

The above script is taking 10 minutes to execute. Is it possible to get this done faster using Julia? Also how can I write extra columns in matching rows from file2 to the output file?

Comment: if you still want to try python further, pandas merge with inner join could be explored here.

Answer (score 1):

Julia could be faster, but I guess something like the following (which I didn't test) will already improve it a lot:

```py
import csv
import sys
import datetime

with open('input.csv', 'r') as fd1:
     with open('compare_input2.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as fd2:
          input1 = csv.reader(fd1, delimiter=",")
          input2 = set(csv.reader(fd2, delimiter=","))
          rows = 0
          matches = 0
          
          with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as wdf:
               writer = csv.writer(wfd, delimiter=",", quotechar = '|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
               
               print(datetime.datetime.now())
               for row1 in input1:
                    if row1 in input2:
                         writer.writerow(row1)
                         matches += 1
                    counts += 1
               print(datetime.datetime.now())
               
          sys.stdout.write(f"{len(input1)} rows compared, {len(matching)} matches found\r")
```

I didn't test it, but the basic tricks are to load the input of of `input2` into a set (for constant time membership check), and only iterate over `input1` (not loading it into memory completely, let alone into tuples).  That should bring down complexity to `O(max(length(input1), length(input2))`.